# Is there a way to insert automator output at the cursor?

Tags: automator

I have a simple script that generates different output every time it's run (e.g. generate a UUID).

Is there a way to write an automator script that simply inserts the output of a script at the current cursor location?

(I want to run this service from Thunderbird, if that makes a difference.)

Comment: It's customary to explain why you're downvoting a post

Answer (score 1):

Could your automator script copy the output to clipboard and then run this script to paste the clipboard contents?

```
do shell script "pbpaste > /path/to/your/clipboard-file.txt"
```

This topic covers the paste function in more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976338/applescript-to-paste-text-from-clipboard-into-a-file

Comment: This would insert the clipboard into the file, but would do so by replacing the *entire* file with the clipboard contents.

Comment: I'm already having my automator script write its output to the clipboard. I then paste the result into my document. I was hoping to just have the automator output go directly to the document without having to be pasted.

Comment: Sorry! I seem to have misunderstood!